# Adding space between two attributes in a pseudo element content

Tags: css, html

I have the following html

```
<div data-price="10" data-currency="USD"></div>
```

and I want to create a pseudo element that displays data in the attributes like this:

```
:before {
 content: attr(data-price) + ' ' + attr(data-currency)
}
```

My problem is that the space is not added between. Is there so special way to achieve it without harding the space in front in the attribute itself? Thank you.

Comment: use    `content: attr(data-price) " " attr(data-currency);`

Comment: The new pseudo-element syntax uses double colon: `::before`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `content: attr(data-price) " " attr(data-currency);` dont use `+` for concatenation

```css
:before {
   content: attr(data-price) " " attr(data-currency);
}
```

```html
  <div data-price="10" data-currency="USD"></div>
```

Comment: The new pseudo-element syntax uses double colon: `::before`

Answer (score 3):

I think of this solution:

```css
.myClass:before {
 content: attr(data-price);
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.myClass:after {
 content: attr(data-currency);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" data-price="10" data-currency="USD"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for here is an answer to whether concatenation by putting a space between two attributes is possible, because it is possible to concatenate two attributes without the space.

Comment: The new pseudo-element syntax uses double colon: `::before`